# What does a/ and b/ stands for in patch header?

Tags: version-control

The first line of patches always has this kind of code:

```
diff --git a/i18nviews.inc b/i18nviews.inc
```

or

```
diff --git a/plugins/views_plugin_localization.inc b/plugins/views_plugin_localization.in
```

What does the a and b  stand for?

Answer (score 3):

A' and the 'B' are prefixes to differentiate source and destination.

You can change the prefixes with

```
--src-prefix=<prefix>
Show the given source prefix instead of "a/".

--dst-prefix=<prefix>
Show the given destination prefix instead of "b/".
```

From http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, just consider `a/` to refer to the "old" file (with filename indicated following the `a/`), and `b/` to refer to the 'new file (with filename indicated following the `b/`).

As an illustration, consider the patch attached to [comment nr 15 in issue nr 1632898](https://www.drupal.org/node/1632898#comment-6412840), which looks like so:

```
--- a/panels_ipe/plugins/display_renderers/panels_renderer_ipe.class.php
+++ b/panels_ipe/plugins/display_renderers/panels_renderer_ipe.class.php
@@ -137,7 +137,10 @@ class panels_renderer_ipe extends panels_renderer_editor {
   function render_pane_content(&$pane) {
     $content = parent::render_pane_content($pane);
     // Ensure that empty panes have some content.
-    if (empty($content) || empty($content->content)) {
+    if (empty($content) || !is_object($content) || empty($content->content)) {
+      if (!is_object($content)) {
+        $content = new StdClass();
+      }
       // Get the administrative title.
       $content_type = ctools_get_content_type($pane->type);
       $title = ctools_content_admin_title($content_type, $pane->subtype, $pane->configuration, $this->display->context);
```

In regular English you could say "Remove that 1 line from `a/` (indicated with '-', located at line 141 in a/`) and insert again these 4 lines from`b/` (indicated with '+', starting from line 141)".

Some more details about the `-137,7 +137,10` part of this patch example:
if you'd browse the `a/` (old) file,  this is how these **7 lines** look like, starting from **line 137**,

```
class panels_renderer_ipe extends panels_renderer_editor {
   function render_pane_content(&$pane) {
     $content = parent::render_pane_content($pane);
     // Ensure that empty panes have some content.
     if (empty($content) || empty($content->content)) {
       // Get the administrative title.
       $content_type = ctools_get_content_type($pane->type);
       $title = ctools_content_admin_title($content_type, $pane->subtype, $pane->configuration, $this->display->context);
```

So to know what the content of `a/` actually looks like (by just looking at the patch), ignore the lines with a "+", and replace any "-" with a blank.

And if you'd browse the `b/` (new) file, this is how these **10 lines** look like, starting from **line 137**:

```
class panels_renderer_ipe extends panels_renderer_editor {
   function render_pane_content(&$pane) {
     $content = parent::render_pane_content($pane);
     // Ensure that empty panes have some content.
    if (empty($content) || !is_object($content) || empty($content->content)) {
      if (!is_object($content)) {
        $content = new StdClass();
      }
       // Get the administrative title.
       $content_type = ctools_get_content_type($pane->type);
       $title = ctools_content_admin_title($content_type, $pane->subtype, $pane->configuration, $this->display->context);
```

So to know what the content of `b/` actually looks like (by just looking at the patch), ignore the lines with a "-", and replace any "+" with a blank.